# Handling errors from wicket form onSubmit

Tags: forms, wicket, onerror

How can I catch and know an error on a AjaxSubmitLink or AjaxButton? The Parameters I have got Overriding onError methods don't tell me which error/s happen/s.
I debugged all components' validation and they were successful.
Could be a problem if there is another form inside the main form (there are a couple of panels which need a form to catch and ponder textarea and input values in order to update).

Comment: Without some code and a better 'description' of the error (like a stacktrace or something) it'll be very hard or impossible to help you.

Comment: Just from reading your description (add some code as already mentioned): There is no such thing as form inside of another form!

Comment: @mrak Well there ist... Wicket allows nested forms (rendered to HTML as single forms) and separates data, validation and all the other stuff in different objects (and classes).

Comment: Thanks for the info! Finally some replacement for multiple submit buttons with setDefaultFormProcessing(false) :)

Comment: Good morning, I will try to explain it better. I'm developing a wicket application, and in a page I have a form where I add input text and a button to submit. I took off all validators but When I click submit, the debugger stops on protected void onError() form method that I override. So, how can I know the error if there is error trace? Next methods don't give me any information about possible error (hasError(),getFormValidators(), validateFormValidators(),hasErrorMessage(),getFormValidators(), getFeedbackMessages()).I realise that I can override callOnError, IFormSubmitter can give me info?

Comment: Sorry.. there is no error trace.

Comment: If the onError Method is called, something called Form.error() before that. So you might want to add a breaktpoint there too.

Comment: It's fixed. Thank you mates!! I set a breakpoint on FormComponent class, exactly on line 1135-(method public void validate()) and check when isValid() return false. Then you can realise the formComponent which produce the error. Thank you again!!